# How to specify a timezone for a joda DateTime object?

Tags: java, jodatime

I have a function that converts a string into a joda time object and formats it.

```
public static String getFormattedDatetime(String someDate) {
    DateTime newDate = DateTime.parse(someDate, DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")).minusHours(7);
    String formattedDate = newDate.toString("dd-MMM-yy hh:mm a");

    return formattedDate;
}
```

The function takes the string and returns a formatted DateTime just fine, but I'm having troubles assigning a TimeZone to it. The string that I'm passing in represents a UTC time from the database that I need to convert to PST/PDT. I can't figure out a way to 1) assign the new DateTime object a timezone and 2) convert that object's timezone to PST/PDT. Right now I am handling this with .minusHours. Certainly not ideal.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Under no circumstances should you use `.minusHours(7)` as it will be wrong half the year, and the `DateTime` object will still think it's in UTC.**

Use `.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("America/Los_Angeles"));`

[Here is a list of all time zones supported by Joda Time with their corresponding IDs](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html)

I recommend refactoring the constant generated by the `forID()` call into a `static final` field somewhere appropriate in your code, and using that everywhere you need to do the conversion.

---

You are probably aware, but to be on the safe side `DateTime` objects are **IMMUTABLE**, which means the `withZone` call will return a brand new `DateTime` instance, and will **not** change the zone of the original object.

---

@anotherdave makes a great point in the comments. You say *PST* in your question, but *PST* is only in use half the year (because of Daylight savings). I assumed you meant the current time in Los Angeles, Seattle, etc. and not specifically the *PST* zone, as those cities use *PDT* in the other half of the year. However, if you DO want *PST* 100% of the time, you can use `forID("PST");`

Comment: Also, unless you specifically want "PST", as opposed to e.g. "the current time in Los Angeles" I would use *durron*'s example of "America/Los_Angeles" rather than `DateTimeZone.forID("PST")` — calling by region name should return you PDT during daylight savings whereas calling by PST will always return PST.

Comment: I've tried that. Like this: `DateTime newDate = DateTime.parse(someDate, DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")).withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("America/Los_Angeles"));` It's still not converting the dates. Is this code just assigning my object a zone without actually converting it? Do I need to assign it a UTC zone first and then convert to PST?

Comment: @QuidFacis My post is the correct answer to **the question you asked**. If you've tried that and it's not creating the behavior you want, please **edit your question** with the exact String input, the exact call you use, what you expect the resulting object should be, and the what the resulting object actually is.

Comment: @durron597 As specified in the question, the input is a string that is parsed into a DateTime object within the function. The input doesn't matter because that parse method always returns me valid DateTime objects in the pattern specified by the function. Shouldn't a timezone method work on any DateTime object?

Comment: @QuidFacis I can't help you if I don't know **what the problem is**. If my answer didn't solve your problem, then I clearly don't understand exactly what is going wrong. My recommended edit will help me to understand more exactly what problem you're having. [Please read this help center post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this one for more details](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

Update: if someone is looking to just change the TimeZone but not the actual Date. Then you can use below code:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parse(date.toString(), DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")).withZoneRetainFields(DateTimeZone.forID("PST"));  // it will change timezone to PST but not the actual date field value.
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
public static String getFormattedDatetime(String someDate) {

    DateTime newDate = DateTime.parse(someDate, DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yy-MM-dd  HH:mm:ss.SSS"));
        LocalDateTime zonedDate = LocalDateTime.parse(newDate, DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"));
        DateTime finalZonedDate = zonedDate.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC);
        String formattedDate = newDate.toString("dd-MMM-yy hh:mm a");
        return formattedDate;
    }
```

I had to use joda's `LocalDateTime` class to assign a timezone when I was converting the string to a variable. Then I had to convert the zone separately.